# javafx gui using ellipses's issues

Tags: java, javafx

I am new to javafx and am trying to make a GUI that has rings of ellipses of different sizes/colors similar to a dart board. the end goal is to make it an animation and have it spin and such but for now I am just trying to get the GUI to look/work properly before I add animation. My issue is when I run the program the GUI comes up blank/empty. I'm not sure as of why so if you guys see something that I don't and have any tips to a rookie please by all means let me know!here is the code I have written so far:

```
package targetpractice;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class targetpractice extends Application {

    private Ellipse[] rings;
    private Color[] colors = {Color.BLUE, Color.RED, Color.YELLOW};
    private final int NUMCOLORS = 3;

    double width = 0;
    double height = 0;
    int numRings = 0;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane pane = new Pane();


        rings = new Ellipse[numRings];
        for (int ringNum = numRings - 1; ringNum >= 0; ringNum--) {
            Ellipse e = new Ellipse(width / 2, height / 2, ringNum * (0.5 * width / numRings), ringNum * (0.5 * height / numRings));
            e.setFill(colors[ringNum % NUMCOLORS]);
            e.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            rings[ringNum] = e;
            pane.getChildren().add(e);
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setTitle("target practice");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to narrow it down at all?

Comment: @SomePerson i've got the error fixed, now I need to make it do animations. I want the rings to jiggle and dance :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing `ringNum` in the `for` loop to `-1`, and iterating as long as it is `>=0`. I.e. you are not iterating at all. Similarly, you initialize the `rings` array to an array of zero items.

Presumably you actually wanted to set `numRings` to something other than zero. Similarly, you probably want to initialize the values of other variables to something sensible as well.

Comment: i changed the numRings = 20; because I want 20 rings in the GUI but i still do not get an GUI that has anything in it :( @james_D

Comment: Perhaps making ellipses with zero width and height isn't going to create anything you can see...

Comment: oh wow hahahahah I've got it now :D wow that was the most obvious thing ever lololol